# Python - How To Decode JWT Header?

Tags: python, jwt

I have a token that includes the following header `eyJraWQiOiI4NkQ4OEtmIiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ`.

How can I obtain the following JSON decoding of it as [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) provides?

```
{
  "kid": "86D88Kf",
  "alg": "RS256"
}
```

`jwt.decode()` doesn't give this header.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an unencrpyted header. Its a URL-safe base64 encoding of a JSON encoding of the data you want. You need to add padding characters to the end of the encoded string to make sure its on a 4 character boundary, then decode.

```
>>> import json
>>> import base64
>>> token = "eyJraWQiOiI4NkQ4OEtmIiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ"
>>> padded = token + "="*divmod(len(token),4)[1]
>>> padded
'eyJraWQiOiI4NkQ4OEtmIiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ=='
>>> jsondata = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(padded)
>>> jsondata
b'{"kid":"86D88Kf","alg":"RS256"}'
>>> data = json.loads(jsondata)
>>> data
{'kid': '86D88Kf', 'alg': 'RS256'}
```

Answer (score 13):

In PyJwt use `get_unverified_header(token)` for that. This is especially useful to obtain the key id (`kid`) before you verify the token. So in the last line I show how to extract the `kid` from the header.

```
import jwt
token = "eyJraWQiOiI4NkQ4OEtmIiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c"
header = jwt.get_unverified_header(token)
print (header)
print (header['kid'])
```

Result:

> {'kid': '86D88Kf', 'alg': 'RS256'}
> 86D88Kf

as described in the [documentation](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html)

Comment: also would like to add that this is in `pyjwt` package.

and to get the decoded body, you can use `jwt.decode(token, options={"verify_signature": False})`